# Bilingual Latent Dirichlet Allocation into [a Modified] K-Means Clustering Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, k-means, lda, naivebayes

I have a thesis paper that focuses on using Bilingual LDA and a modified version (modified for runtime) of K-Means for Sentiment Analysis (using Multinomial NB) on Filipino and English COVID-19 Tweets.

I have the files that came from my Bi-LDA from https://github.com/1991wzc/python-LDA-and-BiLDA/blob/master/BiLDA.py which made text files like theta values, phi values, topic of words and a wordmap (photo of the files attached) [![Bi-LDA outputs] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7On0l.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7On0l.png) from the tweets that were tokenized and lemmatized, basically preprocessed, however, I cannot seem to apply K-Means that came from my Bi-LDA files since I do not know what to do next.

I will also attach the Google Colab of the .ipynb file so you can see what is needed to be put for K-Means:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FE4WkG-cEe1SPmFm49Z6ovA7oREg17VT?usp=sharing

Thank you so much, a little help will surely make a difference for me and my group.

What I did before running the Bi-LDA algorithm is to change the value of K which is equal to the value of K in my K-Means so that it only needs six (6) values once each topic is clustered.

I do not know what to expect, really since I don't know which values are to be put in a K-Means algorithm, but I am expecting after K-Means, I can get to statistical treatments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I could exactly answer your question, but I suppose you have to apply your data using K-Means algorithm.

Based from your source code, I've noticed the following:

1. You are tokenizing your tokens by using .split().  Your code could save a lot of lines and list comprehensions by using libraries such as nltk's tokenizer.
   Since you are tokenizing tweets, you can `from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer`.  Similar steps could be done on lemmatization.
2. Your output files are unstructured, you need to structure it in a way that it could be easily understood.  You can store it in CSV.  An alternative way is to:
3. Store the processed data using Pandas' Dataframe.  That way you'll have access to a table-like structure where you can modify the table they way you want.
4. Instead of coding your own K-Means algorithm,  you can instead import the algorithm `KMeans` from `sklearn.cluster`.
5. Now you can obtain statistical treatments such as scores, cluster centers.  You can also obtain treatments from `numpy`
6. (Addtnl) If you want to visualize your data, you can do so by using packages such as `matplotlib` or `seaborn`

I hope this answer would be helpful for your thesis.  I just saw your Facebook post from a data science group.